# php script to save image with proper extension

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made some javascrit code base on image uploader to save an image to the server using php. This is my code :

```
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var base64 = reader.result;     
        //console.log(base64);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'imageapi.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: {src :base64 },
            type:"POST",
            contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(response) {
              alert('Files uploaded successfully.');
            }
        });
    }
```

The uploaded file should be : text, png or svg

I want to save the file with proper extension on server. Could anyone help to solve my problem ?

I've tried using this code to get extension but it didn't work

```
echo $mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $_POST['src'], FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

Please help me, How to save image on server with proper extension

Answer (score 0):

Following code gets filename at first and then extracts it's extension.

```
$path = $_FILES['src']['name'];
$ext  = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Check this tutorial to upload file http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp